# While editing a commit in `git rebase -i`, have to revert changes in a single file

Tags: git, git-rebase

In an earlier commit, I need to undo all changes to certain files, but keep the changes of other files.

What I'm doing:

- `git rebase -i [sha-ref]`
- edit `git-rebase-todo` changing `pick` to `edit` for the affected commit.

My files are now all in the state they were committed in `[sha-ref]`.
I tried `git restore [file-name]`, but it does nothing. `git restore --staged [file-name]` obviously doesn't do anything, because the changes are not staged.

How can I undo the changes just for one file ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found it:

```
git checkout [sha-ref]~ [file-name]
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Sometimes when I discover this but I'm in the middle of something else, I'll just do your first command for the files I want to restore. (And by the way the new version of that command is `git restore --source=<commit-id> file_name`.) And then commit that with a message like "sq into a1b2c3" (or "fu into a1b2c3" if I know I don't need to update the message). Then I'll rebase -i later when my status is clean.

Comment: @TTT: just checking: "fu" here stands for "fix up", not some other pair of words that can be abbreviated "F" and "U"...? :-)

Comment: @torek LOL. Yes. I write it so often it doesn't even phase me anymore. But I do remember thinking that the first time I wrote it.

Comment: @TTT  You might prefer your own abbreviations, but note that `git commit --squash <hash>` and `git commit --fixup <hash>` will produce commit messages that `git rebase -i --autosquash` will recognize and manipulate. (I don't use the latter very much, but find it convenient when I do actually use it.)